# In git, how do I display the usage overview that I get when I use a command incorrectly, without actually using a command incorrectly?

Tags: git

If I use a git command incorrectly, like

```
git commit -b
```

I get useful usage output on the terminal like so:

```
error: unknown switch `b'
usage: git commit [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...

    -q, --quiet           suppress summary after successful commit
    -v, --verbose         show diff in commit message template

...
```

etc.

How do I get this information to show up without entering an incorrect command? I've tried `git help commit`, but that opens a webpage. `git help -w commit` does the same, while `git help -m commit` and `git help -i commit` don't work at all (on Git Bash for Windows; they do bring up man or info pages on Linux though.)

I can't just "enter an incorrect command" because I don't know beforehand if a command is wrong or not, and I don't want to accidentally destroy my work by entering a command that happens to do something terrible (*hmm, I wonder how I can use push better. Let's bring up the usage with some junk command, how about **git push -f***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-h` switch.

Using `--help` shows the man page, which can obviously also be accessed using `man git commit`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can get around this by doing the following:

```
git commit ---
```

It brings up the information I want, and I'm relatively confident that nobody is going to try to make "-" a real switch, since that would be incredibly confusing. (Let me know if I'm wrong.)

Comment: In the past, I have generally used `-\?` for this kind of test since POSIX `getopt` returns `?` for invalid option letters, but Git internally doesn't use POSIX `getopt`, and `---` actually seems simpler, and yes, someone making a `-` option would be terrible and cruel since `--` in POSIX means end of options and you'd *have* to specify it as `---`. :-)